# DropWizard JAR Signing Bug

Tags: testing, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard, jar-signing

I am trying to unit test my DropWizard 0.7.0 app, just like the [docs recommend](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#testing-applications):

```
@Test
public void runRegisertsLocationResource() {
    given:
    Environment environment = Mockito.mock(Environment)
    JerseyEnvironment jersey = Mockito.mock(JerseyEnvironment) 
    MyApplication fixture = new MyApplication()
    MyConfiguration config = new MyConfiguration()

    Mockito.when(environment.jersey()).thenReturn(jersey)

    when:
    fixture.run(config, environment)

    then:
    Mockito.verify(jersey).register(Mockito.any(LocationResource))
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.DispatcherType"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at io.dropwizard.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:62)
    at io.auditcloud.micros.backend.service.config.BackendConfiguration.<init>(BackendConfiguration.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:186)
    at io.auditcloud.micros.backend.service.BackendApplicationTest.runRegisertsAllProviders(BackendApplicationTest.groovy:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Here are my dependencies defined inside `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile (
        'com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:3.0.2',
        'com.codahale.metrics:metrics-json:3.0.1',
        'com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.4',
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:0.7.0',
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-auth:0.7.0',
        'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2',
        'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:0.7.0',
        'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031',
        'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
    )

    testCompile(
        'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.0'
    )
}
```

What's going on here?

---

#### Update: How to reproduce (step by step)

1. Create a new DropWizard project and use the exact dependencies mention above (I use Gradle but whatever works should be fine).
2. Create a new JUnit test class, say, under `src/test/java`, and make it look exactly like my JUnit test above, *except* replace `MyApplication` with whatever is the name of your DropWizard app's main class, and replace `MyConfiguration` with the respective configuration impl. **Note:** my app is written in Groovy, hence the Groovy syntax; you may need to "Java-ify" my code snippet above to get it to compile.
3. Run the test; you should get the same exception as I have posted above.

Comment: Can you give a simple step by step of how we can reproduce this problem.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet (+1) - please see my update with steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: See UPDATE below**

<s>**This is not an answer. Please don't vote on it. It will be deleted upon confirmation from the OP**</s>

<s>So I'm wondering if you have tested the above steps for yourself. I followed the steps as you've stated, of course creating my own classes (super simple with little to no implementation, since you haven't specified any. And I don't get the result you are experiencing. I am also using Maven and Java. Whether or not the problem is with groovy, I am not sure, as I am not a groovy user.</s>

Below you will find my [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) implementation of your step-by-step. <s>I suggest you create something similar that reproduces the problem. Create a project from scratch, as you have described (maybe using the below example as a starting point), then start adding features until it reproduces the problem. This is also a good way to discover the root of the problem yourself.</s>

I would start with a simple Groovy project, and if a simple project, like the one below causes the problem, then it may be a Groovy problem, and you should edit your post with the MCVE so others familiar with Groovy can try and find the problem.

If it's not a Groovy problem, and you discover the problem by building on top of my MCVE, and you can't figure out the cause and how to fix it, then please do post the MCVE also.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-stackoverflow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <dropwizard.version>0.7.0</dropwizard.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**MyConfiguration**

```
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;

public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {}
```

**MyApplication**

```
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

public class MyApplication extends Application<MyConfiguration> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> btstrp) {}

    @Override
    public void run(MyConfiguration t, Environment e) throws Exception {
        e.jersey().register(new LocationResource());
    }   
}
```

**LocationResource**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/location")
public class LocationResource {}
```

**Test**

```
import dropwizard.stackoverflow.resource.LocationResource;
import io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyEnvironment;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class SimpleDropWizardTest {
    @Test
    public void runRegisertsLocationResource() throws Exception {

        Environment environment = Mockito.mock(Environment.class);
        JerseyEnvironment jersey = Mockito.mock(JerseyEnvironment.class);
        MyApplication fixture = new MyApplication();
        MyConfiguration config = new MyConfiguration();

        Mockito.when(environment.jersey()).thenReturn(jersey);

        fixture.run(config, environment);

        Mockito.verify(jersey).register(Mockito.any(LocationResource.class));
    }
}
```

**Test Result**

[image]

---

## UPDATE

So I seem to have made my MCVE incorrectly. For some reason I missed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
</dependency>
```

And it just so happens, this appears to be the the smoking gun. When I added this dependency to the above project, I would get a *similar* exception, which was not exactly the same, but detailed the same problem during class loading.

If you get rid of this dependency, it will work with the above example. Seems to be a conflict of versions. Dropwizard is already dependent on Jetty 9.0.7.v20131107. You can see the Maven dependency tree

```
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:0.7.0:compile
...
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jetty:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-jetty9:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.0.7.v20131107:compile
```

Basically when you declare a top level dependency (as you have with Jetty), it will supersede any transitive dependencies. So you have a Jetty 9.0.7 artifacts trying to interact with your declared 8.1.14 servlets artifact.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @peeskillet (I'd +1 you but you specifically requested *not* to be upvoted!) - I will send an update later today once I get ahead on a few other things. If you think there is a better format for this type of back and forth troubleshooting (email, IRC, GitHub, etc.) let me know. More to come soon...